# Request to send personal information to Google

Tags: privacy, personal-problems

Well, my company is asking for very personal information to be filled in Google forms, to update the collaborators personal data. Things like Social Security number, Address, Citizen's number, and so on. Basically almost every detail is required. This seems to be an abuse of privacy.

I don't feel comfortable to give this information to Google. What can I do? The people who request this don't have any perception of web security, privacy or integrity of the data.

Comment: Your organisation is using Google Forms to collect info they should already have and you're worried that *Google* will abuse it or cause a data breach? "*What can I do?*" What do you want to do? Push back against the request? Get them to collect the info themselves? Who will you have to contact if you want to do something?

Comment: @Lilienthal yes that is what OP is asking

Comment: Have you brought your concerns to your boss/manager? What did he say? Also, what country are you in? (might be relevant)

Comment: Can you tag with your country to give us some insight which privacy laws may apply?

Comment: Very related question on Security SE "[How secure are Google (Drive) Web Forms?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67005/how-secure-are-google-drive-web-forms)" and "[Should we store personally identifiable information on google drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102491/should-we-store-personally-identifiable-information-on-google-drive?rq=1)"

Comment: @bharal My point was that we don't have enough information here to formulate an answer that isn't unreasonably long and generic. It matters what specifically the OP is against (use of external tool, collection of data) and who he'll have to contact to push back (manager, CIO, HR, CIO).

Comment: To be honest, information stored at Google is probably more secure than on your intranet, assuming there's someone in your company who can physically access your servers.

Comment: @mcknz Always depends on who you don't want to have access ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First make sure that the request is really from your company. Emails can be constructed to appear to be from somebody in the company, but really be from an outside agent who is phishing for valuable information.

If it not from the company report this immediately to your company security. Many companies have a procedure they want you to follow to report the incident.

If the request is from your company direct your questions to the company security office. State your concerns that PII (Personally identifiable information) may be being collected and stored outside the control of the company security procedures. National and local laws may apply to the proper storage and protection of this information.

Comment: tldr: if phishing, alert security. if not phishing, alert security.